# Registered HttpApplication events in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have the following query:
In ASP.NET Global.ascx file following HttpApplication events are defined:

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


   }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

As I can understand, these are HttpApplication event handlers. But there are lots of other events also. Are the Global.ascx events are only registered events? If not then, What are the other events those had been registered?
Also, say I have implemented a HttpModule on implementing Application_BeginRequest eventhandler. Now, the ASP.NET Framework also implemented the same. Then would my implementation overrides the Framework ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can *attach* as many as `handlers` to an event. For more information read `MSDN` pages on -  `Handling events`.

Read MSDN - [Life Cycle Events and the Global.asax file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) and [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

Comment: Can I write the same event handaler in a HTTPModule as well as in the Global.ascx file?

Comment: Yes. You can attach *one* or *more* handlers to an event.

Comment: So, lets conclude ASP.NET Framework had implemented every HttpApplication events. Then, on top of that we can add additional event handlers implementation in Global.ascx and in my own custom defined HttpModules. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No! You are *creating* Global.asax to *handle* application events. (They are not handled automatically - at least handle by creating global.asax or programatically). ASP.NET automatically binds application events to event-handler methods in the Global.asax file using a naming convention of *Application_event* if it is *present*.